# Unable to fetch value of getter

Tags: java

I'm new to coding. I have 3 classes `Payment`, `CashPayment`, and a `MainClass`. I want to access the value of payment class getter into `CashPayment` method. I called `Payment` getter into `MainClass` to set the value of `amountOfPayment` instance and then access the it through getter in `CashPayment`. However, it always returns 0.

**Payment.java**

```
public class Payment {
    public double amountOfPayment;


    public Payment(){}

   
    public double getAmountOfPayment() {
        return this.amountOfPayment;
    }

    public void setAmountOfPayment(double amountOfPayment) {
        this.amountOfPayment = amountOfPayment;
    }
}
```

**CashPayment.java**

```
public class CashPayment {


    public String paymentDetails() {
        Payment payment = new Payment();
        return "Payment : " + payment.getAmountOfPayment();
    }


}
```

**PaymentDriver.java**

```
public class PaymentDriver {
    public static void main(String args[]){



        Payment payment = new Payment();
        payment.setAmountOfPayment(200);
        CashPayment cashPayment = new CashPayment();
        System.out.println(cashPayment.paymentDetails());
}
}
```

**Output** `Payment : 0.0` // This should be 200.0

Comment: i set value by `payment.setAmountOfPayment(200)` and access it through getter but value if always 0.

Comment: In cashPayment.paymentDetails you create a new payment. That's why you get 0.

Comment: `payment` in `main(..)` and `payment` in `paymentDetails()` are two different local variables, which refer to the different objects. You set the field of one object, and then you're trying to get the field from another object.

Comment: Okay! what should i do to solve it?

Comment: Solve what? what you perceive as a problem? I have no idea which object you want to keep and which one to discard.. I have no clue on which object you want to set the field's value.. I have no clue what is your *aim*, what you want to *achieve*. If it's just printing the field obtained via getter, [optional, but important] 1) declare class's field as private, and then 2) use the getter on the same object reference that you use to set the value, before.

Answer (score 3):

You're using a completely different `Payment` object instance in your `paymentDetails()` method than the one you're attempting to reference.

There are numerous ways to fix this. A simple, but not necessarily architecturally elegant way would be to define your `paymentDetails()` method to take a `Payment` argument and pass in the one you've created in `main()`

```
public class CashPayment {


public String paymentDetails(Payment payment) {
    return "Payment : " + payment.getAmountOfPayment();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other options to make it work:

1. Inheritance

If `CashPayment` extended `Payment` class, then its method `paymentDetails` would not require creation of another `Payment` object:

```java
public class CashPayment extends Payment {
    public String paymentDetails() {
        return "Payment : " + this.getAmountOfPayment();
    }
}
```

Then the driver/test method would look as follows:

```java
Payment payment = new CashPayment();
payment.setAmountOfPayment(200);
CashPayment cashPayment = (CashPayment) payment; // casting needed
System.out.println(cashPayment.paymentDetails());
```

Output:

```
Payment : 200.0
```

---

2. Aggregation (instance of `CashPayment` has an instance of `Payment`):

A `Payment` field with a setter needs to be added to `CashPayment` class.  Optionally, this field can be set via constructor.

```java
public class CashPayment {
    private Payment payment;

    public void setPayment(Payment payment) {
        this.payment = payment;
    }
    
    public String paymentDetails() {
        if (null != payment) {
            return "Payment : " + payment.getAmountOfPayment();
        }
        return "No payment set";
    }
}
```

Driver class update:

```java
Payment payment = new Payment();
payment.setAmountOfPayment(200);
CashPayment cashPayment = new CashPayment();

System.out.println("before setting: " + cashPayment.paymentDetails());
cashPayment.setPayment(payment);
System.out.println("after setting: " + cashPayment.paymentDetails());
```

Output:

```
before setting: No payment set
after setting: Payment : 200.0
```